# Running EJB persistent timer after WAR version change

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly

I have an application which runs persistent timers on a `Wildfly-18` in standalone mode. These are simply fired by the `Timerservice`.

```java
@Stateless
class MyTimerService {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    public void registerTimer() {
        TimerConfig timerConfig = new TimerConfig("identifier", true);
        timerService.createSingleActionTimer(executionDate, timerConfig);
    }

    @Timeout
    void timeoutTimer(Timer timer) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

And in essence this works fine, until a new release is made. This is because of the following as stated in their [documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/19.1/Developer_Guide.html#timer-service):

> A persistent timer will be identified by the name of the EAR, the name of the sub-deployment JAR and the Bean’s name.
> If one of those names are changed (e.g. EAR name contain a version) the timer entry became orphaned and the timer event will not longer be fired.

So after a new release, there will be a new folder in the `data` folder. But old timers are orphaned and no longer executed.

```
wildfly-18.0.1/standalone/data/timer-service-data
├───my-application-1.0.0.my-application-1.0.0.MyTimerService
│       6a14484b-3a62-4345-bcc2-1507ca9b6223.xml
│
└───my-application-1.0.1.my-application-1.0.1.MyTimerService
```

It looks like you can only change the top-level folder (`timer-service-data`) looking at the [model-reference](https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/18.0/subsystem/ejb3/service/timer-service/file-data-store/index.html). But not the fact that each new release will be a new folder.

We would like to keep the version name in the `war`. Is there a way to keep referencing to the same folder after a new release? Or run the old orphaned timers anyway?

Comment: Why? The old timer is deprecated (it no longer exists).

Comment: @josejuan I wouldn't say it's deprecated. If an event was scheduled to be run in 5 days and I make a new release today, I'd still like the event to run when it was scheduled. Regardless if I either just reboot the server or deploy a new version, it was still scheduled to be run.

Comment: your previous versions are deployed also? (In any case, this strategy is, in my opinion, an anti-pattern)

Comment: @josejuan No, there is only 1 version deployed. The latest. If V1 created a timer, V2 should still be able to execute it. Otherwise persistent timers make little sense to me, unless you never rename your war.

Comment: Some ideas in case they help: First, do you REALLY REALLY need the version in the file name? Second, if the deployment happens with some kind of pipeline, you may add a step moving (or copying) the xml files from the old folder to the new. *Maybe - just maybe* that will be enough and it is quite cheap in terms of implementation and coupling. Then, maybe try to recreate the new xml file based on the contents of the old, again during the deployment process, i.e. read the old and write the new yourself. Good luck anyway!

Answer (score 0):

A persistent timer is only persistent under service restarts not under codebase redeployment (specifically under artifacts version changes).

From the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=liberty-developing-enterprise-bean-ejb-persistent-timer-applications):

> Also, note that EJB persistent timers are associated with an EJB based on the application name, module name, and bean name. If an application is updated, and any of these names change, then the timer continues to exist in the database, but appears to no longer exist as it no longer expires and runs.

My recommendation is that you treat any infrastructure state as volatile (except for those specifically persistent such as the file system, database, etc... and for which secure state management is done).

For this particular case, when the system is restarted, you could check which `Timers` have been left pending and reconfigure them again, however, my recommendation is to use a specific queueing strategy (e.g. a prioritized queue in some *MQ). This will make it resilient to service failures, it can be processed in parallel, in a distributed way, auto-scaling, etc...